# redirect en wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

necesito hacer un redirect de una página si el usuario no esta logueado, una vez que inicie sesión que lo redirija de nuevo a la página en la que estaba, ¿Alguien tiene algún ejemplo?

```
    if(empty($user))
        {

      login();

            return null;
        }

function login(){
  if(!$current_user->user_login){
  
    header("location:login.php"); 
  } else{
    wp_redirect( home_url("area-privada") );
  }
  
}
}
```

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pega esta función el el **functions.php** de tu tema de WP

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 's_webprivada' );
function s_webprivada(){
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ){
        // Obtenemos la página actual  
        global $wp;
        $url_actual = home_url(add_query_arg(array(),$wp->request));
            
        // Redireccionamos
        if ( preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $url_actual)
            != preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', wp_login_url()) )
        {
            wp_safe_redirect( wp_login_url( $url_actual ), 302 ); exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Funciono a la perfección. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

El location que tienes puesto no funciona?
yo pondría el location en tal caso de que no te funcione en mayúsculas la "L" a veces no hace distinción de dicha función en minúsculas
Asegúrate de que el loguin está en la misma carpeta ya que si esta en otra deberas moverte hacia donde este el directorio y demás...

ejemplo:  header("Location:../login/index.php");